# Creating a link with implode only makes one array item a link?

Tags: php

```
$fidimp = implode('"', $fidarr);
$friendsimp = implode('<a href="../profile?id=', $funamearr);
$impglue = '</a><br />' . $fidimp . '>';
echo('<a href="../profile?id=' . $fidimp . '>' . implode('</a><br />', $funamearr));
```

This is the code I'm working with.

`$funamearr` has 2 values in it: "Conner" and "Rach667"

`$fidarr` has 2 values in it as well: "2" and "3" (the user's id's)

When this code is run, it only makes "Conner" a link (it works, by the way) How can I make it so that "Rach667" shows up as a link too?

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @hjpotter92 I'm trying to create a link to the profiles of the users on the friends list, but the only username out of the 2 that shows up as a link is the first one.

Comment: When working with implode and explode functions, they will always return an array if more than 1 value is found. You will nees to loop through this array, which you're currently not doing, so it will only ever echo out one result.

Comment: @LokiSinclair Sorry, I'm not entirely sure how to do that. However, it's echoing both results, but only one is a link.

Comment: Sorry, was called out. And was on my cell this morning, so coding on a phone isn't helpful and prone to many mistakes. There have been a couple of answers now explaining what I meant. Hopefully these will help you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First build an associative array from your ids to your names, then create an array of links and implode it, something like:

```
<?php

$funamearr = array( "Conner", "Rach667" );
$fidarr = array( 2, 3 );

$users = array_combine($fidarr, $funamearr);

foreach($users as $id => $name) {
    $links[] = sprintf('<a href="../profile?id=%s">%s</a>', $id, $name);
}

echo implode('<br/>', $links);
```

Comment: I'll try this out when I get home. Looks promising!

Answer (score 1):

Well I don't recommend using implode in this case but as said by LokiSinclair to use a loop.

```
<?php
foreach($funamearr as $key => $value) {
    echo '<a href="../profile?id=' . $fidarr[$key] . '">' . $value . '</a><br/>";
}
```

This case assumes that the array keys of `$funamearr` and `$fidarr` match with eachother.

Outside the code I would make two tips.

1  Use usefull variable names.

`$funamearr` is not telling me much, except the arr part because it probably is an array. I would recommand `$usernames` (multiple so array ;)

2  Keep data together

No we have to hope that the keys are the same. but if you keep the data at the same level we won't and ofter easier in use

ie

```
array(
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'test',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 2,
        'name' => 'test_name_2',
    ),
)
```